# Optimizing loop with few instructions(SSE2, SSE4) with TBB

Tags: optimization, image-processing, parallel-processing, tbb, sse2

I have a simple image processing related algorithm.
Briefly, an image(mean) in float is subtracted by an 8-bit image
the result is then save to an float image(dest)

this function is mainly written by intrinsics.

I have tried to optimize this function with TBB, parrallel_for,
but I received no gain in speed but penalty.

What should I do ? Should I use more low-level scheme such as TBB task
to optimize the code ?

```
float           *m, **m_data,
                *o, **o_data;
unsigned char   *p, **src_data;
register unsigned long len, i;
unsigned long   nr,
                nc;

src_data    =   src->UByteData;    // 2d array
m_data      =   mean->FloatData;   // 2d array
o_data      =   dest->FloatData;   // 2d array
nr          =   src->Rows;
nc          =   src->Cols;

__m128i xmm0;

for(i=0; i<nr; i++)
{
    m = m_data[i];
    o = o_data[i];
    p = src_data[i];
    len = nc;
    do
    {
        _mm_prefetch((const char *)(p + 16),  _MM_HINT_NTA);
        _mm_prefetch((const char *)(m + 16),  _MM_HINT_NTA);

        xmm0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) (p));

        _mm_stream_ps(
                        o,
                        _mm_sub_ps(
                                    _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_srli_si128(xmm0, 0))),
                                    _mm_load_ps(m + offset)
                                )
                    );
        _mm_stream_ps(
                        o + 4,
                        _mm_sub_ps(
                                    _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_srli_si128(xmm0, 4))),
                                    _mm_load_ps(m + offset + 4)
                                )
                    );
        _mm_stream_ps(
                        o + 8,
                        _mm_sub_ps(
                                    _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_srli_si128(xmm0, 8))),
                                    _mm_load_ps(m + offset + 8)
                                )
                    );
        _mm_stream_ps(
                        o + 12,
                        _mm_sub_ps(
                                    _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_srli_si128(xmm0, 12))),
                                    _mm_load_ps(m + offset + 12)
                                )
                    );

        p += 16;
        m += 16;
        o += 16;
        len -= 16;
    }
    while(len);
}
```

Comment: I would not be surprised if IPP already had a function for this.

Comment: If you are using the Intel compiler, why not just write a naive version of the function and see if the compiler can vectorize it itself?  I don't know about GCC in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost no computation here, relative to the number of loads and stores, so it's likely that you are being limited by memory bandwidth rather than computation. This would explain why you don't see any improvement in throughput when you optimise the computation.

I would get rid of the `_mm_prefetch` instructions though - they are almost certainly not helping here and may even be hurting performance.

If possible you should combine this loop with any other operations that you are doing before/after this - that way you amortise the cost of memory I/O over more computation.

Comment: why _mm_prefetch isn't useful in this case ?

Comment: @prgbenz: _mm_prefetch needs to be issued a couple of hundred clock cycles ahead of any potential cache miss, and only helps if you have bandwidth to spare - putting it immediately before the relevant loads isn't going to help, and may even impact on any automatic prefetching that the CPU may already be doing. On top of that it wastes cycles in what is already quite a short loop.